# SQLite PCL raw core could not be loaded into Tizen.NET NUI application

Tags: c#, sqlite, tizen, tizen-tv, tizen-tv-emulator

So, I created a new Tizen .NET application based on the template I have in VS 2022:
[image]

It has the .NET 6.0 Framework, with the target framework being `net6.0-tizen7.0`

[image]

Now, I followed the SQLitePCL.raw tutorial over in its official [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw), which means I have to install (via Nuget) these sets of packages:

- sqlite-net-base (to enable SQLite)
- sqlitepclraw.core (the core package)
- sqlitepclraw.provider.e_sqlite3 (the provider that will use SQLite)
- sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3

[image]

In the Initialize() function of my Tizen app, I added

```
SQLitePCL.raw.SetProvider(new SQLitePCL.SQLite3Provider_e_sqlite3());
SQLitePCL.raw.FreezeProvider();
```

[image]

which is essentially just a sanity test to make sure the NuGet package works. However, running it via emulator gives me this:

[image]

`Could not load file or assembly 'SQLitePCLRaw.core, Version=2.1.6.2060, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1488e028ca7ab535'. The system cannot find the file specified`

Looked at all of the horror stories about this, including changing the versions, uninstalling and reinstalling, and even including SQLitePCLRaw bundles for some Batteries.Init() solutions, but none of those work. It keeps giving me the same error at the Initialize() function.

Heard of issues with the target framework as well, so I tried creating a different project template (Blank App (Tizen.NUI)) which has a target framework of. And that seems to work with all of the initial packages I installed.

[image: different project template]

[image: same nuget packages]

[image]

However, I really need the target framework `.net6.0-tizen7.0` because that's where all of my project has already started to be built into, so I can't really use different templates. Thoughts or workarounds? How do I make my Tizen.NET app see SQLitePCLRaw.Core?